# Changing data service from BlazeDS to PHP

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, blazeds

Recently started to learn Flex technology to create RIAs. And now I want to create web based application of my created program in C++ builder. (flight info sys)

I liked the Flex because of it's cross platform and animation rich possibilities. One of the best web applications that i faced with in the inet is http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/devnet/networkmonitor/main.html
it has wonderful animating grid possibilities. Its server technology is in Java.
How about converting this data service to PHP? That should read data from mysql in PHP..
I prefer working with PHP (as data service) and MySql (as rdbms) in Flex...

seeing animated grid is so cool :)) Switch to Grid mode!

Is it possible to convert it's Data service to php?

Comment: Have you read this - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex_php.html or this http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_php_architecture.html.

Comment: Now I can load data from mysql in flex app!!!

Answer (score 0):

Flex is a client side technology that is server-side agnostic. There are a number of ways you can use PHP to get what you want. The preferred approach for maintenance and performance would be using AMFPHP which allows you to define a PHP based destination that behaves like Blaze DS with respect to AMF.

Comment: Actually, there is Zend framework that has AMF (for communication between PHP and flex client using binary mode and short length requests) in or you can download server CE that has all of them!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you would want to combine to system that do exactly the same thing? blazeds uses AMF and flex data service will ask you to download Zend which contain amf for php if you are using php server.

If you are using php as the flex server, connecting to mysql server is very easy, you would probably need blazeds if you are using other database server such as mssql server and so on.

php server is the best way to go in flex using flash builder 4 and above with mysql server.